# Babel/Node: how to mix import/export syntax with top-level await

Tags: javascript, node.js, babeljs, top-level-await

I am starting a Node.js project that uses react-pdf. This means that I need Babel to transpile the TSX syntax into JS code. I am having big trouble to make it work properly. If I want to use `import/export` syntax, my `package.json` must say that `"type": "commonjs"`. But, as far as I'm aware, if I want to use top-level await `type` property must be set to `"module"`. I don't really know what is the difference between both.

So, I set `"type": "commonjs"`, I receive the following error:

```
const token = await getAuthToken();
              ^^^^^

SyntaxError: await is only valid in async functions and the top level bodies of modules
```

And now, when `"type": "module"`:

```
var _react = _interopRequireDefault(require("react"));
         ^

ReferenceError: require is not defined in ES module scope, you can use import instead
```

I can see that the transpiled files use `require()` syntax, which is not allowed when type is set to "module". So, isn't there any way to make Babel transpile to `import/export` syntax, so I can both use this syntax AND top-level await feature?

[EDIT]: As asked, there goes my .babelrc configuration file:

```
{
  "presets": [
    [
      "@babel/env",
      { "targets": { "node": 18 } }
    ],
    [
      "@babel/preset-react",
      { "targets": { "node": 18 } }
    ],
    [
      "@babel/preset-typescript",
      { "targets": { "node": 18 } }
    ]
  ],
  "plugins": [
    "@babel/plugin-proposal-class-properties",
    "@babel/plugin-proposal-object-rest-spread"
  ]
}
```

If it's important, my `package.json` script line is:

```
"run": "babel --extensions .ts,.tsx src -d output && node output/document.js"
```

Comment: "*If I want to use `import/export` syntax, my package.json must say that `"type": "commonjs"`*" - uh, no, `import` and `export` are ECMAScript **module** syntax. It seems like you have babel configured to transpile them back to commonjs syntax? You should remove that. If you need help with this, show us your babel configuration.

Comment: @Bergi .babelrc posted. If there is other configuration file that Babel uses, I am not aware.

Comment: wondering if your front end and back end are independent?Like your backend does not include your front end? your front end just fetch data from your backend?

Comment: Actually there is no front end. I am making a PDF generator with [react-pdf](https://react-pdf.org/), so I can use React to style the document. That's why I need to use Babel.